# webpack url-loader copied image can not open

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, urlloader

In main.jsx ,image haven been compiled to base64 dataurl,
and copied in bundle file(f67531eee03d5b3f45d6d010c1a2ce13.png) but can't open by both browser and webstorm , show format error as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfRX9.png)

### main.jsx

```
   import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import discountPng from 'url-loader?limit=30000&mimetype=image/png!./back.png';
console.log(discountPng);

const  test= <img src={discountPng}/>
ReactDOM.render(test, document.getElementById('header'));
```

### config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
module.exports = {
    entry: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', './WxXqg/src/main.jsx'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'WxXqg/bundle'),
        publicPath: '/static/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx','.png']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

    ],
    module: {
        /* preLoaders: [
         {test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,loader: "source-map-loader"}
         ],*/
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,loader: 'babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react,presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=stage-2,presets[]=stage-3'},
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
           /* { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'file-loader' },*/
            { test: /\.jpg/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpg" },
            { test: /\.gif/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif" },
            { test: /\.png/, loader: "url-loader?limit=30000&mimetype=image/png" },
            { test: /\.svg/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg" }
        ]
    }
};
```

### console.log

here is my the browser and list

- [enter console.log description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpqRU.png)

Comment: is there someone can help me ,i have been dealt this problems for few days

Comment: oh no  it is amazing i just remove  url-loader in webpack.config and it worked thanks my god!